# I am Getting Error in the expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I have a An expression on one of the column in Tablix like

```
    =Iif(month(today)="5", Fields!H1Quota.Value+Fields!Q3Quota.Value+Fields!AprQuota.Value,
iif(month(today)="6",Fields!H1Quota.Value+Fields!Q3Quota.Value+Fields!AprQuota.Value+Fields!MayQuota.Value,
iif(month(today)="7",Fields!H1Quota.Value+Fields!Q3Quota.Value+Fields!AprQuota.Value+Fields!MayQuota.Value+Fields!JuneRevenue,
Fields!H1Quota.Value+Fields!Q3Quota.Value)))
```

In the above expression ,i have set a condition based on the excecution month.It was showing error in preview,but it is not showing anything in as red lines but getting the error,
IS the above syntax correct?

Comment: try putting spaces while adding the fields, like :- `Fields!H1Quota.Value + Fields!Q3Quota.Value + Fields!AprQuota.Value`

Comment: Thanks bhupesh,I forgot to put .value,Its working now